# How to calculate Gradient 'direction' (not magnitude) of image along x and y axis in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I used imgradientxy() ;but it gives values like -600.i need values of angle in range -180 to 180. in both direction separately.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The values are 0 and 90. The gradient is calculated in the X and Y direction by `imgradientxy()` as you may infer from its name.

However the gradient in a point is defined by:

[image]

and you can do `[Gx,Gy]=imgradientxy(img)`.

That means that your total gradient (not the "directional gradient", which is what Gx and Gy are) is a vector. the `(Gxi,Gyi)` vector in point `i`.

To calculate the modulus and angle of a vector is a straightforward algebra thing:

The modulus, magnitude, euclidean norm or however you preffer to call it is:

```
m=norm([Gx,Gy]);
```

And the angle:

```
theta=atan(Gy/Gx); %radians
theta=atand(Gy/Gx); %degrees
```

Comment: Or you can just use `imgradient` which outputs both magnitude and direction directly.

Comment: @nkjt Well yeah, indeed! But using `imgradientxy` the OP learns something XD